# Complexity of algorithms - Competitive Analysis

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

For example we have an algorithm with the complexity `O(n log n)`. An online algorithm for the same problem is 5-competitive. What is the complexity of the online algorithm?

In my opinion the result should be something like `O(5 * n log n)`. Did I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation refers to the asymptotic complexity of a function. The simplest way to explain this is that it means no constant are included in the notation. That means that `n log n`, `5n log n`, and even `10^6*n log n` all fall in to the big-O class of `O(n log n)`

Comment: I am aware of this. But I am trying to solve it with the known formula:

    ALG(σ) ≤ c * OPT(σ)